# Detect specific url and add tracking parameters PHP

Tags: php, regex, parameters, preg-replace

I've a question, that seems simple but who's causing me some problems.

I've a text string that can contains multiple html tags, paragraphs and links (text link and/or html links ). I would like to parse the content, detect links with a specific URL, and only in this case, apply tracking parameters in the url.

Example : I would like to add the parameters only on urls that starts with google.com.

```
$string = 'This is the content... <a href="yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> - <a href="google.com">This one will be surcharged with ?tk=test</a> and direct links too : google.com";
```

How can I do that ? I tried with regex, but it's not working. I tried with preg_replace, but URL can have multiple forms (with http or not, different tld, etc).

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `preg_replace` with `/href="([^"?]*google\.com[^"]*)"/` as the pattern. ( `"` are escaped in the php below)

```
$string = 'This is the content... <a href="yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> - <a href="google.com">This one will be surcharged with ?tk=test</a>';

$output = preg_replace("/href=\"([^\"?]*google\.com[^\"]*)\"/", "href=\"$1?tk=test\"", $string);

echo $output;
```

Returns:

```
This is the content... <a href="yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> - <a href="google.com?tk=test">This one will be surcharged with ?tk=test</a>
```

This should append `?tk=test` to the end of any href that includes `"google.com"`
https://regex101.com/r/7eoohe/3

---

**Updated regex to not match urls like `https://search.yahoo.com/?p=google.com`

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks spencer! That's a nice debut. But I would like to intercept direct links too like google.com without <a href=""> tag. Also, how to detect urls with subpages like google.com/page ? Thanks!!

Comment: As you can see from the examples here (https://regex101.com/r/7eoohe/6), it does detect urls with subpages. As for what you're calling "direct links", I would do a second preg_replace for the substring `" google.com "`